# How to make query range mandatory?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I have an AOT Query object. How can I make a `range` a mandatory field?

[image: MandatoryFieldQuestion]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot make the range value mandatory.

You can test (in `validate`) whether the range is empty or not.